# Unrecognized field when mapping from Firebase data structure to JAVA object

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the data structure which I am trying to map to a JAVA object but I can't figure it out how to properly map the **groupId** property.
Can someone tell me how it is done? 
[[image: roupWithGroupId firebase datastructure]

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "1" (class firebasetest.model.GroupWithGroupId), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: , "lastGroupId", "hourLimit", "maxLimit", "minLimit", "groupId", "actualLimit"])
    08-09 19:04:43.130 8259-8259/firebasetest I/System.out:     at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: firebasetest.model.GroupWithGroupId["1"])
08-09 19:04:43.130 8259-8259/firebasetest I/System.out:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2615)
```

and the Java object:

```
  public class GroupWithGroupId {
        public long actualLimit, hourLimit,lastGroupId,maxLimit,minLimit;
        public Map<String, Object> groupId = new HashMap<>();
        private GroupWithGroupId(){}

        public GroupWithGroupId(final long actualLimit, final long hourLimit, final long lastGroupId, final long maxLimit, final long minLimit) {
            this.actualLimit = actualLimit;
            this.hourLimit = hourLimit;
            this.lastGroupId = lastGroupId;
            this.maxLimit = maxLimit;
            this.minLimit = minLimit;
        }

        @Exclude
        public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            result.put("actualLimit", actualLimit);
            result.put("hourLimit", hourLimit);
            result.put("lastGroupId", lastGroupId);
            result.put("minLimit", minLimit);
            result.put("maxLimit", maxLimit);
            result.put("groupId", groupId);
            return result;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `@IgnoreExtraProperties` from your class.

Try something like the following (note I haven't tested this but hopefully it will help!):

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

        @IgnoreExtraProperties
        public class Location {

                public Double latitude;
                public Double longitude;

                public Location() {}

                public Location(Double latitude, Double longitude) {
                        this.latitude = latitude;
                        this.longitude = longitude;
                }

                @Exclude
                public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
                        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                        result.put("latitude", latitude);
                        result.put("longitude", longitude);
                        return result;
                }
        }

        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public String email;
        public String phone;
        public Location location;
        public Date lastUpdated;
        public Date signUpDate;

        public User() {}

        public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                this.email = email;
                this.lastUpdated = new Date();
                this.signUpDate = new Date();
        }

        @Exclude
        public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
                HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                result.put("firstName", firstName);
                result.put("lastName", lastName);
                result.put("email", email);
                result.put("phone", phone);
                result.put("location", location.toMap());
                result.put("lastUpdated", lastUpdated);
                result.put("signUpDate", signUpDate);
                return result;
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It helped, but I had to modify a bit the toMap() function for the proper funtcioning. See my solution below

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the **toMap()** function in GroupWithoutGroupId and now it works properly!

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class GroupWithoutGroupId {
    public long actualLimit, hourLimit,lastGroupId,maxLimit,minLimit;
    public GroupID groupID;
    public String groupIDkey;

    private GroupWithoutGroupId(){}
    public GroupWithoutGroupId(final long actualLimit, final long hourLimit, final long lastGroupId, final long maxLimit, final long minLimit) {
        this.actualLimit = actualLimit;
        this.hourLimit = hourLimit;
        this.lastGroupId = lastGroupId;
        this.maxLimit = maxLimit;
        this.minLimit = minLimit;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("actualLimit", actualLimit);
        result.put("hourLimit", hourLimit);
        result.put("lastGroupId", lastGroupId);
        result.put("minLimit", minLimit);
        result.put("maxLimit", maxLimit);
        result.put(groupIDkey, groupID.toMap());
        return result;
    }

    @IgnoreExtraProperties
    public class GroupID {
        public long sum;
        public Map<String, Object> users = new HashMap<>();

        public GroupID(){}
        public GroupID( final long sum, final Map<String, Object> users) {
            this.sum = sum;
            this.users = users;
        }

        @Exclude
        public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            result.put("sum", sum);
            result.put("users", users);


       return result;
            }
...
```